# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method WP_Screen::is_block_editor()

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've got suddenly this error when I want to add an article to a website, done in WordPress I inheritated:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method WP_Screen::is_block_editor() in /homepages/35/d161758243/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/redux-framework/redux-templates/classes/class-templates.php:79 Stack trace: #0 /homepages/35/d161758243/htdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): ReduxTemplates\Templates->add_body_class(' acf-admin-3-8 ...') #1 /homepages/35/d161758243/htdocs/wp-includes/plugin.php(203): WP_Hook->apply_filters(' acf-admin-3-8 ...', Array) #2 /homepages/35/d161758243/htdocs/wp-admin/admin-header.php(195): apply_filters('admin_body_clas...', '') #3 /homepages/35/d161758243/htdocs/wp-admin/edit-form-advanced.php(483): require_once('/homepages/35/d...') #4 /homepages/35/d161758243/htdocs/wp-admin/post-new.php(76): include('/homepages/35/d...') #5 {main} thrown in /homepages/35/d161758243/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/redux-framework/redux-templates/classes/class-templates.php on line 79

As plugins are updated automatically, I cannot see which one triggered the error, I tried to desactivate some of them to check, without success. I cannot access the plugin Redux Framework through the admin interface.

Anyone has a clue? Thanks in advance.